# API Request - Store JSON - Analyze it later

Tags: python, json

I wanting to GET a JSON request from an API and then save those values for comparison and use for another API request. First I am having trouble saving the table.

```
def get_sma(ticker_symbol, API):
     url = f"https://api.twelvedata.com/sma?symbol={ticker_symbol}&interval=1day&time_period=200&outputsize=1&apikey={api_key}"
     response = requests.get(url).json()
     return response
```

Using this method how do I recall the response, is it using "get_sma" ?

Comment: By recall the response I mean how do I use that JSON array later, like say I do another API call and I want to compare the values of list 1 versus list 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a key, but here is how to clean up the code you posted.

```
import requests


def get_sma(ticker_symbol, api_key):
    url = f"https://api.twelvedata.com/sma?symbol={ticker_symbol}&interval=1day&time_period=200&outputsize=1&apikey={api_key}"
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    return response

aapl_response = get_sma("AAPL",None)
print(aapl_response)
amzn_response = get_sma("AMZN",None)
print(amzn_response)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am wondering how do I use the JSON from that get request. I think it has to do with json.load or loads. Or JSON dump. But I am wanting to save the info from the request and then use that as input later. I think your solution works I just dont undesrstand it fully yet :)

Comment: In my example, appl_response has a python Dict with all the information. You work with that dict the same way you work with any other python Dict. If you mean save as in save a file, search for how to save a file with python in SO.

Comment: I guess this is more my problem I want to be able to use this response as the stock symbol for the other API call.

Comment: response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
r = json.loads(response.text)

# UNCOMMENT BELOW TO SHOW THE JSON OUTPUT PRETTIFIED
# print(json.dumps(r, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ':')))

for stock in r['symbols']:
    print(stock['symbol'], stock['watchlist_count'])

Comment: Yeh its perfect! I want to take this trending list, and then use it as "ticker_symbol"